Existence of an element of a group whose order is the same as that of its congruency class
Let $G$ a finite group , and $H$ a normal subgroup of G. Let $x$ be an element of $G$ and $\bar{x}$ its congruency class in $G/H$.
Let $c \in G/H$, such that :  $ord(c) \wedge |H|=1$. Show that there exists $x \in G$ such that : $\bar{x} = c $ and $ord(x)=ord(c)$
My attempt:
Let $x$ be a representative of $c$ in $G$ ( i.e $\bar{x} =c$ ) , then $\forall h \in H , xh$ is also a representative of $c$ .
First, we prove that $ord(c) | ord(xh)$. Indeed :
$(\overline{xh})^{ord(xh)} = \overline{ (xh)^{ord(xh)}}= \overline{1}$
Hence by properties of groups and their orders we have that $ord(c) | ord(xh)$
Then $\forall h \in H : ord(xh)=ord(c)  m_h$
Now using the assumption about $ord(c)$ and the cardinal of $H$ we have by bezout's lemma   the existence of two integers $a$ and $b$ that verify :
$a\cdot ord(c) + b |H| =1$
Here i want to prove that $\exists h \in H : m_h \equiv a\pmod{|H|}$
so that i can have an element $xh'$ whose order is relativaly prime with $|H|$ , and by a similar arguemnt as the one described above ,show that $ord(xh')=ord(\overline{xh'})$ and hence conclude.
However  i can not , i tried to use a pigeonhole but without effect . Any guidance is appreciated

Consider $x=x^1$ and expand the $1$ according to Bezout.

"$ord(c) \wedge |H|=1$": so, is $H$ trivial?

@Kan't as far as I can tell this is OP’s notation for the gcd.

@ahulpke i apologize but i can't seem to find a solution based on that hint , as for the notation $\wedge$ it refers to the gcd , sorry for the confusion.

@AdamBoussif you write $x=p\cdot q$ with $p=(x^{ord(c)})^a$ and $q=x^{b|H|}$. Show that $\bar x=\bar q$ .

yes but why does that imply that $ord(q)=ord(c)$

Let $x$ be some representative of $c$. As in ahulpke's comments, by Bezout, $x = x^{a \cdot ord(c) + b|H|}$ for some integers $a$ and $b$, and in $G/H$ this equation becomes $c = c^{a \cdot ord(c) + b|H|} = c^{a \cdot ord(c)} c^{b|H|} = 1^a c^{b|H|} = c^{b|H|}$. Therefore $q = x^{b|H|}$ has $\bar{q} = c^{b|H|} = c$.
Since $c^{ord(c)} = 1$, in $G$ this becomes $x^{ord(c)} \in H$. Therefore $x^{ord(c)}$ has order dividing $|H|$, so $x^{|H| ord(c)} = 1$. This implies $q^{ord(c)} = (x^{b|H|})^{ord(c)} = x^{b|H| ord(c)} = 1^b = 1$ as well, so $ord(q)$ divides $ord(c)$. You have already shown that $ord(c)$ divides $ord(q)$.
Therefore, $q$ is the element of $G$ that we are looking for.
